# WSO2 EMM - Unable to unregister from iOS Device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, wso2, wso2-iot

We were able to configure WSO2 EMM on our remote server properly and able to make android working fully. For iOS also we got through to registering the device and applying a couple of policies.

We are not able to perform following operations from iOS.

- Unregister Device
- Ring
- Other functions related push notifications.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can perform the lock operation successfully and the policies are applying to the device with out any issues. This can be due to a issue in your MDM APNS certificate. Please verify the validity of the certificates.

You can follow the below articles to generate valid certificates.

- [How to setup Apple Push Notification (APN) service for WSO2 EMM iOS Agent](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM220/Generating+an+MDM+APNS+Certificate)
- [Generating an MDM APNS Certificate](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM220/Generating+an+MDM+APNS+Certificate)

At the mean time you can simple remove the device management profile from the settings in order to dis-enroll the device.